# Extra quotes in a variable read from dialog in bash

Tags: linux, bash, dialog

I need to configure user.email for git in bash script, and my problem is that I don't know how to get this line to run: `git config --global user.email "user@example.com"`

right now my code run this this command without double quotes - `user@example.com`

and I tried to escape " " in every way that I found and almost every time the code run `'"user@example.com"'`

a fragment of my code in bash:

```
function get_email(){
    e_mail=/tmp/tmp.sh.$$
    dialog --clear \
        --title "EMAIL" \
        --inputbox "Enter your email" 8 40 2>"${e_mail}"
    email=$(<"${e_mail}")
    git config --global user.email "$email"
}
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: More to the point, have you tired echoing `email` right after you set it?

Comment: That this code don't change the settings. When I run `git config --list` I don't see e-mail, and code run without any errors

Comment: Yes I tried, but every time I get '"user@example.com"' and nothing is changed

Comment: Have you tried running this code line by line manually from the command line?

Comment: Sorry for odd comments. Getting used to new phone keyboard.

Comment: I only run git config --global user.email user@example.com, but I'll try to run whole function and I let you know in a minute

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried replacing the dialog-to-file-to-variable molarkey with just `email="user@example.com"`?

Comment: Backing up here. In `git config --global user.email "$email"`, the quotes given there are *syntactic*: They're instructions to the shell about how to treat the contents of the variable, telling the shell to treat those contents as literal. That's exactly what you want.

Comment: Now, what you should do is look at whether your `/tmp/tmp.sh.*` files include *literal* quotes in them. That is, if **the contents of the files** are having `"`s written into them by `dialog`. If that's true, then the shell will be (entirely correctly!) including those literal quotes in the argument list passed to `git config`.

Comment: I run `email="user@example.com" git config --global user.email "$email"` and nothing changed

Comment: You need a semicolon. When you do `foo=bar echo $foo`, then `foo` is in the *environment* for the `echo` command, not substituted into its arguments. Same thing for `git config`.

Comment: Which is to say, `email="user@example.com"; git config --global user.email "$email"` will work.

Comment: File `/tmp/tmp.sh.*` don't have `""` - how can I change that?

Comment: It's not supposed to have literal quotes. Don't change it.

Comment: OK, so what I need to change? my git config still have my email instead of `user@example.com`

Answer (score 1):

`dialog` can under some circumstances (man page goes into detail) put literal literal double quotes in its output (which can be replaced with literal single-quotes using `--single-quoted`).

To strip them back out, use parameter expansion -- as shown in the below:

```
get_email() {
    local email

    email=$(dialog --stdout --clear \
        --title "EMAIL" \
        --inputbox "Enter your email" 8 40
    )
    git config --global user.email "${email//'"'/}"
}
```

---

Some notes:

- `"${email//'"'/}"` expands `$email`, replacing all instances of `"` with an empty string. **This is the solution to your immediate problem**. The syntax involved is parameter expansion, documented at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe
- Don't use the `function` keyword. It makes your code incompatible with POSIX shells for absolutely no benefit.
- Declare your locals with `local` (this isn't POSIX-defined, but even `ash` and `dash` support it) to prevent leaking into the surrounding scope.
- Use `--stdout` on `dialog` to allow capture of output with command substitution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you tell me how I can call it? :D

Comment: Hmm? The function is invoked with `get_email`.

Comment: Now, nothing is happening

Comment: Are you sure you added the `--stdout` option?

Comment: To be clear, I actually tested this myself, and it *did* edit my `~/.gitconfig` file appropriately, using [dialog 1.2-20150920](http://www.invisible-island.net/dialog/CHANGES.html). But there are many different versions of dialog; if you're using a different one, YMMV.

Comment: ...note also that this code doesn't redirect stderr (because with `--stdout`, stderr is being used for dialog's communication with the TTY). If you still left the stderr redirection in your own code, that would explain why you aren't seeing any output. Be sure you test with my answer **exactly** as it's given before reporting that it doesn't work. (Could also be that you have a different, incompatible dialog implementation; would have to know exactly which one to do anything about that).

Comment: ok i forgot $ in `email=$(dialog` but now i can write this email, but `git config --list` still shows an old email

Comment: Does `git config --global --list` still show that? Could be in your repo-local config.

Comment: Use `set -x` to see which commands the function actually calls when invoked; that way we can track down whether it's doing the call you expect it to, or if we have something else going on.

Comment: output: `+ email=user@example.com` `+ git config --global user.email user@example.com`

Comment: well -- if it's running `git config --global user.email user@example.com`, and that's what you entered into dialog, then it's working perfectly. Which... huh... means that now we have a git problem, as opposed to still having a dialog problem; maybe the tag needs to come back.

Comment: If you run that same command on its own manually, does the result of `git config --global --list` change? If not, then we have something that's a pure git issue isolated, with no need for it to be a question about shell scripting or dialog or such. (OTOH, building reproduction steps for that question might be somewhat interesting -- likely to mean including state of both `~/.git/config` and `~/.gitconfig`, if you have both, and any other config sources -- ie. environment variables)

Comment: when i run `git config --global user.email user@example.com` in terminal it worked - do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Are you running a bigger shell script that does this and other things as well, or *just* running the lone function in isolation? Can you reproduce the problem in the latter state?

Comment: Frankly, this is overwhelmingly likely to be an environment or context problem -- something being run on the other side of a `sudo` command, or with a non-default `HOME`, or with other environment variables or context that impact exactly where the config files being edited are. Without seeing your system and *exactly* how it's set up, any speculation about how exactly this is failing would be sheer guesswork.

Comment: it's part of a bigger script (about 700 lines) - it's simple graphical editor with python and expect scripts

Comment: (If this *is* being run on the other side of `sudo`, for instance, it could be editing `/root/.gitconfig`, rather than your own `.gitconfig`).

Comment: Yeah. I can't debug your 700-line script for you; you'll need to figure out how to reproduce the bug using only content you can fit into your question.

Comment: ok i need to run whole script with sudo - it can still be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that will absolutely cause the problem at hand, for the reason I gave above. `git config --global` is working, in that case, but it's editing the config files for root, not for yourself.

Comment: (Just Say No to excessive privilege escalation -- even if you fixed it to edit files in the correct directory, you'd then [in several common cases -- ie. when using the atomic recreate-and-replace update mechanism] have files in your home directory *owned by root*, which you couldn't edit further without using `sudo`).

Comment: ok, thank you for the answer! I will look at the code in few hours, and then I write if I fixed this :)

Comment: I know that running this simple script with sudo is a crime, but I couldn't find a way around - I think I will need to rewrite this :D

Comment: good stuff and pluse uno for tech support ;-) Happy new year to all.

Comment: running script with sudo was the problem - after changing my code, everything is working - thank you so much for your help!